# How to give a vector a single name as though it were a column of a data.frame?

Tags: r

I would like to name a vector such that `write.table(vec, "testfile.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)` has a header of value `col1`. How can I do this?

I tried the obvious `names(vec) <- "col1"` but understandably that names the first element `col1` (not the vector itself).

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do in the way that I'm trying to do it? (obviously the vector could first be converted to a 1 x n data.frame and then named, but I wanted to know if that step could be skipped and the vector itself, rather than specific element(s), could be named in a simple one-liner

#### Extra note

To be very clear `write.table(vec, "testfile.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)` will write a 1 x n csv; that's the desired output, just with a specific column name rather than the default ('x')

Comment: Use the `col.names` option: `write.table(vec, "testfile.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names = "col1")` See `?write.table` for more details

Comment: @duckmayr thanks! that solves it. I am still interested to know if a vector can have a name in the same way it could if part of a data.frame ?

Comment: In one sense it already does (`vec`). However, I don't believe what you're specifically asking about is possible. A list or a dataframe (which technically is a list) consists of (potentially) named objects, which are often atomic vectors such as your `vec`. In other words, the names you're thinking about are names for the *elements* of a dataframe. As you've seen, if you try to apply this paradigm to a vector, it tries to make names for the *elements* of the vector. I'm not sure what the useful purpose of having an object-level name for a vector (other than its, you know, name) would be.

Comment: To make it more general, use @duckmayr's solution with `col.names = deparse(substitute(vec))`.

Comment: Or just make it a one-column data frame: `vec = data.frame(col1 = vec)`. But I think `duckmayr` has the key answer for understanding: `vec` *already has a name*, and that name is `vec`.

Comment: @Gregor Calling that a name might create confusion later on (e.g., with named vectors). Technically it's the symbol the vector is bound to.

Comment: @Roland Just so; I was a little loose with the language, thanks for the more precise statement